# Android (Xamarin) How to crossfade text in button

Tags: android, animation, text, xamarin

I have a button with a transparent background that uses a custom icon font.
This button is kind of a shopping card.
When the user adds an item to their order I have it doing an animation where it grows then shrinks back down as well as goes from 50% opacity to 100% then back.
This looks nice, but our designer wants a little more pop.
So the idea is to fade from one text character to another one, then back.
I am attaching pictures the two text characters.

So after all the background info the question is:
Is there any way to animate the change of the text property on a button without doing something like fading between two different views or using images. I am already using a property animator to change the opacity and I was hopping that there would be an easy way to do this as well.

Thanks in advance!

[First Character for shopping cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtKHW.jpg)

[Second Character for shopping cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnhbA.jpg)

Comment: i am not sure if i anderstood correctly. but have u tried using tint with aplha?

Comment: I am already fading the Alpha, but what I want is to fade between two different strings. I am using font icons rather than text, but it would be the same if you wanted to fade from "1" to "2". I have seen a textswitcher, but i need to do this in a button.

Comment: As far as I know, android did not provide such API to do button text fade. As a workaround I suggest you to use imageview to replace the button. Because you are using the font icons. 

And using imageview transition to fade in and fade out.

Comment: I don't think an image view would work. I am not using images rather a font character.